# Как правильно обработать клик по нескольким компонентам когда нужно чтобы активный был только 1?

Tags: reactjs

Есть родительский компонент и у него есть несколько компонентов (массив через map).

Нужно при клике выделять компонент, а из других наоборот удалять выделение.
Я положил переменную текущей активной папки (activeFolder) в redux.

А вот как правильно обработать клик вне компонента чтобы если ни на один из компонентов не было клика, то тогда activeFolder = null
?

Comment: можно код компонентов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повесить onClick на body

```
body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if(!e.target.hasClass('folder')) { // проверяем, что кликнули не на фолдере
        // Сгенерировать событие изменения в вашем store activeFolder = null
    }
});
```